# I wrecked my server: best way to move forward?

Tags: 16.04, server, mysql, nextcloud

As I said, my server is wrecked. Not entirely, just partially.

I have a headless server running Ubuntu 16.04, and can reach it over SSH (and FTP via ssh port).
On it, I have a modded minecraft server running in a screen (works fine), and a webserver in /var/www (development environment).
Said webserver uses MySQL for a database.

Now, yesterday I started installing ownCloud on it, which had stuff to do with MariaDB, I got as far as to go to the webpage to make an admin user, where it just asked me to log in. Tried some stuff, didn't work. So I tried to remove it and am fairly (but not completely) certain that I got most of it.

Then I tried the same thing with NextCloud, got to the webpage to make an admin user and got an empty page (HTML error 500/503), so a PHP error IIRC. Got fed up with this too after trying stuff, and once again tried to remove it.

However, somewhere during the above process, I lost access to my MYSQL database. More specifically, when I log in using `mysql` command or `www.domain.com/phpmyadmin` webpage, I get this error:

```
#2002 - No such file or directory<br />The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

I remove'd, remove --purge'd, purge'd and whatnot a few variations of mysql*, mysql-client mysql-server mysql-common, done autoremoves, autocleans, apt-get -f installs, remove'd some more, reinstalled mysql-server and here is where I'm almost certain it'd be easier to backup the minecraft server and webserver, and reinstall ubuntu cleanly.

Only problem there is that I need physical access, which I currently don't have (I'm spending the christmas holiday at my parents' place), however I live an hour away so it would be manageable to go for a few hours and back.

> Main Question:
>   How would I go about getting my server completely operational again with a working MySQL, and preferrably NextCloud installed on it?

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: If you still have ssh access, simply reinstall mysql (or mariadb), and set up stuff again?

Comment: I tried that, but after that I cannot access mysql with `root` and either no password or the one I set it to (which is gone of course, after removing it), but using no password gives `Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)` which I set during ownCloud setup (which also is gone already, because of deinstalling). I'm seriously debating doing a clean install now :(

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html - that's a fairly trivial problem to fix. Start mysqld with `mysqld --skip-grant-tables`, login, set pasword, stop mysqld, start normal way. And the best thing - you learn something about your system doing it.

Comment: `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start --skip-grant-tables` produces an error, [this](https://pastebin.com/NWfR8Rtx) is the export of `systemctl status mysql.service`. Seems that because of installing MariaDB in the past, it now chooses that one as DB program? Even though I think I deinstalled both and only reinstalled mysql in the end. [Here](https://pastebin.com/LRyWedft) is a pastebin output of `apt list --installed`, seems that it remembers MariaDB still somehow?

Comment: No, not /etc/.... Stop mysqld, and as root run `mysqld --skip-grant-tables`. If you search this site, and google, you will probably find point by point how to do it. Or make a question on how to reset root password for mysql here.

Comment: `mysqld stop`, then `mysqld --skip-grant-tables`, then with `sudo` in before the second command, then with `sudo mysqld start --skip...`, boils down to [this log](https://pastebin.com/c7N3hew2)... (all four of them!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70860/discussion-between-vidarlo-and-diamundo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some discussion in chat...

First problem was that `/var/run/mysql` did not exist. This explains the error message

```
#2002 - No such file or directory
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

as this socket is located in `/var/run/mysql/`.

Next problem was that the user table was corrupt, so when starting with `sudo -u mysql mysqld --skip-grant-tables` to start without authentication, mysql did not want to update the `user` table:

```
ERROR 1728 (HY000): Cannot load from mysql.user. The table is probably corrupted
```

As user had backup of database content, the easiest option at this point was to simply remove all database files, with `sudo rm -Rf /var/lib/mysql/`, and reinstall mysql-server. This ensured that mysql recreated the user table upon installation.